# Evitar que la estructura de la web se mueva cuando se carga el CSS

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Tengo un search-banner centrado en la página de inicio, pero cuando carga la página, ésta se mueve y quiero que permanezca fijo en el centro.

Por favor, si alguien me puede decir con qué código CSS puedo arreglarlo.

Puedes verlo en acción aquí: https://quisqueyacasas.com/

Comment: favor de traductir la pregunta, estas en SO en español; de lo contrario terminará cerrada

Comment: Agrega más detalles a tu pregunta, revisa [ask], modificala para ser reabierta , saludos.